# creating a log file in powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-2.0

I have the following powershell code in which,
backup of (original) files in folder1 is taken in folder2 and the files in folder1 are updated with folder3 files.

### The concept of hotfix !!

> ```
> cls
> [xml] $XML = Get-content -Path <path of xml>
> $main = $XML.File[0].Path.key
> $hotfix = $XML.File[1].Path.key
> $backup = $XML.File[2].Path.key
> Get-ChildItem -Path $main | Where-Object {
>     Test-Path (Join-Path $hotfix $_.Name)
> } | ForEach-Object {
>     Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $backup -Recurse -Container
> }
> write-host "`nBack up done !"
> Get-ChildItem -Path $hotfix | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $main -force}
> write-host "`nFiles replaced !"
> ```

Now, as the backup of files is taken in folder2, I need to create a log file which contains - **name of the file whose backup is taken, date and time, location where the backup is taken**

Can anyone please help me with this?
I did the following code, but its of no use, as I cannot sync the both.

> ```
> cls
> $path = "C:\Log\Nlog.log"   
> $numberLines = 25
>
> For ($i=0;$i -le $numberLines;$i++)
> {
>  $SampleString = "Added sample {0} at {1}" -f $i,(Get-Date).ToString("h:m:s")
>  add-content -Path $path -Value $SampleString -Force  
> }
> ```

*Any help or a different approach is appreciated !!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-PassThru` switch parameter to have `Copy-Item` return the new items it just copied - then do the logging immediately after that, inside the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock:

```
| ForEach-Object {
    $BackupFiles = Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $backup -Recurse -Container -PassThru
    $BackupFiles |ForEach-Object { 
        $LogMessage = "[{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}]File copied: {1}" -f $(Get-Date),$_.FullName 
        $LogMessage | Out-File ".\backups.log" -Append 
    }
}
```

Comment: ok @Mathias .. but I need to print the date and time as well. How should I pipeline them?

Comment: Use `Get-Date` inside the loop to retrieve current date and time, then format a log message with the `-f` operator. Answer updated